# Azure VM via RPD shows black screen and cmd only

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, rdp

I have an Azure Virtual Machine. When I log in through RDP I can see only black screen and CMD console is opened. Is it possibile that there is no explorer?

```
VM OS spec:
Operating system: Windows
Publisher: MicrosoftWindowsServer
Offer: WindowsServerSemiAnnual
SKU: Datacenter-Core-1803-with-Containers-smalldisk
Version: latest
```

I have tried multiple things:

1. Connect RDP through 3 different apps (Windows Remote Desktop Connection, Windows Remote Desktop Connection Manager, Remote Desktop Manager)
2. Opened RDP session with lower resolutions.
3. Opened RDP session with lower color depth.
4. Opened RDP session without bitmap caching.
5. When I press CRTL-ALT-END i can see console LogonUI.exe [image]
6. When I try add new task through TaskManager (File->Run new task -> explorer.exe) I got error `Windows cannot find explorer.exe` [image]
7. When I navigate to C:\Windows where explorer should be installed, there is no explorer.exe. [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SKU you selected is **Datacenter-Core-1803-with-Containers-smalldisk**.  Windows Server Core is a GUI-less version of Windows, well except a few tools that is.

[This article](https://medium.com/@RealNetwork/windows-server-core-2019-gui-management-sysinternals-utilities-datacenter-standard-hyper-v-dashboard-265801412c89) describe what's available and how to extend Core a little bit.