# Azure Service Fabric ImageStoreService fails

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I have problem with my ServiceFabric ImageStoreService. I have a Service Fabric cluster with 5 nodes deployed to Azure. ImageStoreService it is in Error State and I don't know why. Where can I found some more information?
I can not deploy any apps to fabric because it can not connect to ImageStoreService.

```
2020-04-28T11:14:54.0075126Z Service fabric SDK version: 4.0.470.9590.
2020-04-28T11:15:22.0238846Z Copying application to image store...
2020-04-28T11:19:43.2215895Z ##[error]Unable to establish connection with image store service. Please retry.
```

[Service Fabric Explorer screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7uyo.jpg)

The error that I can see in SF Explorer:

```
Partition is in quorum loss.
ImageStoreService 5 3 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000003000
  S/P Down _backend_0 132155143930757796
  S/S Down _backend_4 132155144192909202
  P/I Down _backend_3 132155144192909203
  S/S Down _backend_2 132155144192909204
  S/S Down _backend_1 132155144192909205
```

I've checked free disk space on each one VM and there is at least 10GB free space.
I'm not able to check EventViewer logs on VMs because of other problem with RDP connection do VMs [SF VM RDP problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61500523/azure-vm-via-rpd-shows-black-screen-and-cmd-only) (Windows Server Core is a GUI-less version of Windows).

Comment: Is the cluster certificate valid?  Can you see an error message against the ImageStoreService itself?

Comment: Yes, cluster certificate is valid and there is no error message against ImageStoreService.

Comment: I recommend that you call MS Support for this one.